# How to disable mscorlib.dll from within visual studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I am trying to use a custom standard library in visual studio 2013 and can't seem to figure it out. I have no problems compiling on the command line using /nostdlib although I would like to be able to take advantage of intellisense in the IDE. I have removed all references except for my custom corelib and I am getting conflicting code errors due to having two variations of mscorlib.

The VS documentation says:

> **To set this compiler option in the Visual Studio development environment**
>
> 1. Open the **Properties** page for the project.
> 2. Click the **Build** properties page.
> 3. Click the **Advanced** button.
> 4. Modify the **Do not reference mscorlib.dll** property.

Although this does not seem to be the case, as this option does not exist. Does anyone know how I can disable mscorlib.dll in vs2013?

Comment: It used to be there, but I just checked on VS Express, cant see it either... Hack the project file maybe? Maybe it can be emulated with a portable library? Definitely still there in VS2010.

Comment: It seems to be missing, I checked it with VS 2013 professional. I think it is a case for the Microsoft support.

Comment: Found this forum post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/34e15fbf-6281-49f3-9b22-5b98d416b0e6/vs2012-pro-advanced-build-setting-for-c-nostdlib-setting-is-not-showing-up?forum=visualstudiogeneral - maybe adding  `<NoStdLib>True</NoStdLib>` to your project's file manually will help?

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question, but, indeed - while the UI option has disappeared (or moved) and the documentation remains misleading to this day, you can still replicate the effect by adding `<NoStdLib>True</NoStdLib>` into your .csproj near the other options found in advanced settings:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <NoStdLib>True</NoStdLib>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
...
</Project>
```

Comment: I was wondering where that option went away after VS 2010. Glad that you posted. `NoStdLib` tag works!

Answer (score 0):

To workaround the same problem in *Visual Studio 2017*, adding the following Property Group declarations inside the *.csproj* file (you can unload project from Visual Studio and Right Click and choose Edit) did the trick to suppress the compiler errors:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>    
  <DisableHandlePackageFileConflicts>true</DisableHandlePackageFileConflicts>
</PropertyGroup>
...
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="mscorlib">
  <HintPath>..\path to custom mscorlib.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```